# Visual Studio parameter alignment restrictions and Windows x64 ABI

Tags: windows, visual-c++, 64-bit, sse, abi

With Visual C++ on WIN32 there's a long-standing problem with functions with 4 or more SSE parameters, e.g.

```
__m128i foo4(__m128i m0, __m128i m1, __m128i m2, __m128i m3) {}
```

generates an error:

```
align.c(8) : error C2719: 'm3': formal parameter with __declspec(align('16')) won't be aligned
```

To compound the problem, Visual C++ still needlessly imposes the ABI restriction even if the function is `__inline`.

I'm wondering if this is still a problem on 64 bit Windows ? Does the ABI restriction still apply on x64 ?

(I don't have access to a 64 bit Windows system otherwise I'd try it myself, and an extensive Google search hasn't turned up anything definitive.)

Comment: According to [Agner Fog's "Calling conventions" manual (section 7.2)](http://www.agner.org/optimize/), Windows64 passes all __m128 parameters by pointer, so 4 or more __m128 parameters should not be a problem there. (Cannot check this because I also have no access to a Windows system).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass as many 128 bit SSE intrinsic parameters as you like under x64. The x64 ABI was designed with these types in mind.

From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthk2dkh.aspx):

> __m128 types, arrays and strings are never passed by immediate value but rather a pointer is passed to memory allocated by the caller. Structs/unions of size 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits and __m64 are passed as if they were integers of the same size. Structs/unions other than these sizes are passed as a pointer to memory allocated by the caller. For these aggregate types passed as a pointer (including __m128), the caller-allocated temporary memory will be 16-byte aligned.

Comment: Thanks - it sounds like it's time to start targeting Windows x64 only - do you happen to know the minimum version of Windows and of Visual Studio that I would need in order to build and run x64 executables ?

Comment: VS2008 I think. There is XP64 but that's pretty much unused. Vista 64 probably sensible min level.

Comment: Thanks - that's a big help.